# no sound after upgrading to 15.04

Tags: sound

I have upgraded my system to ubuntu 15.04. And now there is no sound what so ever. My ubuntu is running on a ACER Aspire M5620 with a realtek sound card. I have tried several methods provided on the FAQ-forums, but nothing seems to help. Can anyone provid me with a new solution for this problem?

Comment: I think this http://askubuntu.com/questions/613370/no-audio-after-updating-to-15-04 may help.

Comment: Try running pulseaudio --start in a terminal.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem by doing the following (choose options depending on your hardware):

1. Run the program "PulseAudio Volume Control"
2. Select "Output devices - Port: Headphones"
3. Choose "Configuration - Profile: Analog Stereo Output"

Comment: For me (on a Dell D600) I had to Choose "Configuration - Profile: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output"