# Analog sound output does not appear in "Sound settings"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 15.04, alsa, system-settings

I recently moved my computer, and after I set my speakers up again, I've had problems with outputting sound on them. It just doesn't work.

The sound card is a Asus Xonar DX. I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 with Gnome. Kernel `3.16.0-31-generic`.

I get sound on it by running `aplay -l`, and running `aplay -D plughw:2,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` where `2,0` represents sound card and device respectively:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD1989B Analog [AD1989B Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: AD1989B Digital [AD1989B Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: AD1989B Alt Analog [AD1989B Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: DX [Xonar DX], device 0: Multichannel [Multichannel]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: DX [Xonar DX], device 1: Digital [Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This should mean that the device is connected and working, but that the problem is with sound settings?

[Alsa Information](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b92a2d2b1b4a4a43e7a72fb6c6d79044626d1e81)

Thanks for all help, it is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I've tried a clean install of Ubuntu Gnoem 15.04. I still have the problem. Seems it is with Pulseaudio, that it is impossible to choose my audio device with it for some reason.

**EDIT2:** Thought maybe it was the infamous randomsound-issue, but found that it's not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to solve this, although not a optimal solution, it'll work.

I installed [PulseAudio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/). Then went to "Configuration" and under the correct sound card, I chose the correct output (Analog 5.1).

[image: PulseAudio Volume Control]

Then it shows up in sound settings again. Although, if I change the device in Sound Settings, I sometimes have to open PulseAudio Volume Control the analog sound show up again.

[image: Sound Settings]

Thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614831/no-sound-after-upgrading-to-15-04) question and answer.

Comment: Dead lilnk to pulseaudio volume control.

Pulseaudio volume control not available on Ubuntu via installable apps.

Answer (score 19):

This solution did not work for me for Ubuntu 18.04. But as I executed

```
pactl load-module module-detect
```

the missing built-in Audio Analog Stereo suddenly appeared in the sound settings menu. As I chose it, I was able to hear the sound.

If you want this setting permanent, add the line `load-module module-detect` to the default modules in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

Comment: This worker for me. Was thinking it was hardware related...

Comment: Thanks - i'm on Pop!_OS 20.10 and just during the day my audio cut out and "built-in audio analog steroe" (e.g the headphone jack on the motherboard) disappeared. This brought it back.

Comment: Thanks! Ubuntu 20.04.1 and this solved my issue

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, /etc/pulse/default.pa already contains this (but did not work):  `### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif`

So, maybe some problem related to udev originally?

Comment: @MarkusJunginger Check if your sound device is recognized at all, that means do you see it with #lshw? If not, then maybe you need to install drivers first. If it's recognized, but not loaded, then either you gave to load it or maybe another module is blocking it and you have to blacklist the blocking module, difficult to say now. I had similar issues with my new computer. My network controller is too new, so I had to install drivers first and then I had to manually blacklist another module to get the correct network module working. Obviously it worked automatically after installing the driver

Comment: It brought it back but selecting did not produce sound.

Comment: Run the command works but put 'load-module module-detect' into '/etc/pulse/default.pa' does not. Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

******mine was same  like  you  i upgraded from 14.10  to 15.04 and i fix it****
following these steps**

- open terminal
  type :sudo apt-get install pavucontrol

open pavuontrol from terminal or  dashboard

- Then
  At configuration tab choose in built in audio then choose "***analog stereo duplex***"
- Now
  choose headphones in output device tabs instead of line-out!

use your earphone/headset to check first

then you have  sound  now  play song videos any-thing  ;) enjOy goodday