# No sound after upgrading to 15.10

Tags: upgrade, sound, pulseaudio

Situation:

- After seeing the [EOL reminder](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14921/eol-notice-vivid-vervet-15-04-reaches-end-of-life-on-february-4-2016?cb=1) I decided to upgrade my 15.04 to 15.10 and I did so using the terminal (`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`) without any problems during the upgrade.
- After the upgrade, everything seems to run just fine **except there is no sound,** and full-screen video is now jaggy instead of smooth. Both these things worked just fine before the upgrade. (Yes, that fullscreen video problem is another thing I'll have to figure out.)
- In Skype and other chat apps, I see that my computer receives audio from the other party, and the app shows that it is playing the audio - it just doesn't reach the speakers.
- I know that my microphone (Logitech webcam) is working fine. I see it in Settings>Sound and also my Skype partner can hear and see me.

Steps I've tried:

1. I've checked the physical connection: the speakers work, and they are connected to the correct port. I didn't touch the audio hardware since forever, so I'm fairly sure the software upgrade is the culprit.
2. in Settings>Sound, "line out - built-in audio" is selected by default and looks good to me.
3. `sudo alsa force-reload` didn't help [[A]](https://askubuntu.com/a/613918/5786).
4. `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio && sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio && sudo alsa force-reload` didn't help [[A]](https://askubuntu.com/q/692844/5786).
5. `aplay -l` looks reasonable to me [[Q]](https://askubuntu.com/q/692844/5786):

   > ```
   > **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****  
   > card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]  
   >   Subdevices: 0/1  
   >   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  
   > card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]  
   >   Subdevices: 1/1  
   >   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0  
   > card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]  
   >   Subdevices: 1/1  
   >   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   > ```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

- I did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` then restarted - and sound is now playing again!
- But now the sound notification icon is missing. I just did a `sudo apt-get install indicator-sound` and after a restart everything was back to working again.